# Al crear componentes en Angular no incluyen el método ngOnInit. Cuál puede ser el inconveniente?

Tags: angular, componentes

Cuando creo componentes en Angular no incluyen el método ngOnInit. Cuál puede ser el inconveniente? Es necesario incluirlo? Puede generar inconvenintes en mi proyecto si no está?

Intenté crear los componentes con Angular Schematics o desde los comandos de la consola y de ningún modo genera el método en dentro de los componentes.

Comment: Hola Chechu, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: No es obligatorio que esté. Si no se usará es mejor no ponerlo.

Answer (score -1):

Trataré de responder tus preguntas conforme las realizaste:

**1. ¿Cuál puede ser el inconveniente?**

Esto depende de la versión de angular que estés usando, las nuevas versiones de angular ya no incluyen el método ngOnInit perteneciente al lifecycle hook OnInit.
Es por esto que aunque crees un componente desde 0, **ya no lo incluirá en las nuevas versiones** (15+); sin embargo, en dado caso de necesitarlo, puedes agregarlo manualmente.

**2. ¿Es necesario incluirlo?**

Realmente no es necesario si es que no lo ocupas, si todo se va a realizar el tu constructor o en algún otro método del ciclo de vida de tu componente, realmente no hay problema.

**3. ¿Puede generar inconvenientes en mi proyecto si no está?**

No, ya que solo incluyes lo que usar, tiene relación con tu pregunta 2.

**Notas:**
Esto y otros cambios son los que se presentan en las nuevas versiones del framework, te dejo un link que describe lo nuevo en la versión 15.

https://devm.io/angular/angular-15-features-javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.